# Return response from UnityWebRequest as method return value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity web request to fetch some data from our API. I have a code written like this that works just fine:

```
IEnumerator SendPostCoroutine(String body)
{


    using UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(apiUrl + "/bet");
    www.method = "POST";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    UploadHandlerRaw uH = new UploadHandlerRaw(byteArray);
    www.uploadHandler = uH;
    www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

    www.SetRequestHeader("Session-ID", SceneRoulette.sessionId);

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
    {

        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("POST successful!");

        String str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);

        response = JObject.Parse(str);
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to make my SendPostCoroutine function return the response from the API (json object). I'm new to C#, and have ready many stuff about how yield return works, but still I can't figure it out, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't really directly since the request runs asynchronously but your calling method immediately continuous (otherwise you would freeze the entire app until the request is done) .. see the duplicate links. You either can use a field like you seem to already do or use a callback